# Bulk API in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

Is it possible to Bulk inject contacts in a journey using API ?

I tried to use the contactEvents method but i have a 500 server error. 
contactEventsTest is a DE created using the template "Event DE" from the wizard.

Here is my payload :

```
{   
"eventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx",
"data": [{
    "name": "contactEventsTest",
    "id": "e856d8a7-e7a1-e711-80e3-1402ec819dd8",
    "items": [{
        "values": [
            {
            "name": "ContactKey",
            "value": "ContactKey1TEST"
        },
        {
            "name": "Gain",
            "value": "123"
        }]
    },
    {
        "values": [
            {
            "name": "ContactKey",
            "value": "ContactKey2TEST"
        },
        {
            "name": "Gain",
            "value": "321"
        }]
    }]
}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per winter '24 release, it is now possible to inject multiple contacts into a journey with a single API call: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_2024_winter_jb_enter_contacts_with_api.htm&type=5

I have searched for the actual REST endpoint documentation, but so far it hasn't been published.

Comment: You can find the doc in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_interaction/enterContactsIntoJourneyInBatches.html

Answer (score 5):

***this is not officially available for use BUT...***

Try the endpoint 
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction-experimental/v1/batchcontactevents 
and then something like the following system

```
    {
  "EventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-052645c7-f26d-4f86-2222-52719af046f1",
  "ContactPersonType": "Contact",
  "CallerSystemName": "Salesforce",
  "RecordCount": 1,
  "BatchDetails": [
  {
    "Data": {
      "Type": "Article",
      "TouchPoint": "AccountName"
    },
    "contactKey": "0035E0000075fgDQAQ"
  }
]
}
```

It is the same thing which is used by the MC Managed Package. It works up to 500 records per batch but the Managed Package does batches of 200.

Comment: Update on this, using "ContactPersonType": "Contact" now seems to break the decision splits in Journey, so avoid using this attribute, even tho it is still in the managed package :D

Comment: can you be more precise, what do you mean by break the decision splits ? All contacts fall in the Reminder path ? This is weird :D @Doug

Comment: Hey, it was to do with Salesforce contacts being evaluated using a randomly generated Id instead of the contact/lead Id if they were deleted in Marketing Cloud. Therefore any decision split using the contact/lead Id in the relationship evaluated in unexpected ways (for example all going into remainder)

Comment: This route appears to be deprecated now.